# Converting column values into datetime to insert into AccessDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, ms-access-2016

I am trying to populate values of Pandas Dataframe into MS Access table. I am using the following Pandas built-in `DF.iterrows()` to iterate through each row of a DataFrame and insert each row into Access table.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    print(repr(row['Vote_date'])) #Using iterrows() temporarily converts datetime64[ns] values into Timestamps  
    row['Vote_date'] = row['Vote_date'].to_pydatetime() #This converts all values in this column, except NaT values.

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Vote(vote_date) VALUES(?)", row['Vote_date'])
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
pyodbc.DataError: ('22008', '[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Datetime field overflow  (36) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Pandas `Timestamps` values cannot be inserted into MS Access table. Research has shown that I would need to convert the column values into Python `datetime` values in order to insert into Access DB.

Is there another iteration method that I can use to successfully insert Python `datetime` values into MS Access? And also handle `NaT` values?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just converting it to datetime and then running the loop?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html

```
df['Vote_date'] = df['Vote_date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
df.loc[df['Vote_date'].isnull(),"Vote_date"] = None
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Vote(vote_date) VALUES(?)", row['Vote_date'])
```

Comment: @ Gabrieal A - Yes, I already did try converting all the values in the column to Python `datetime` using `to_pydatetime()`. However, this function cannot convert `NaT` values successfully.

Comment: Try replacing all NaT values with None . I updated my answer with how you might do this

Comment: @ Gabriel A - I tried your updated answer, but got the following error: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_pydatetime'`

Comment: @Mook fixed the issue.

Comment: @ Gabriel A - I tried your updated answer, but `NaT` values remain as they are. Do you know how I can check if a dataframe column is nullable (e.g. it can contain Null/None values)?

Answer (score 0):

I had luck doing this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(['01/01/2019',None], columns=['datetime_field'])
df['datetime_field'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_field'])

df['datetime_field'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime_field'], errors='coerce').where(df['datetime_field'].notnull(), 0.0)
```

Originally the nulls in this field are NaT.

pandas [where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) docs